# Get Contents of Custom List in NetSuite via PHP Toolkit

Tags: php, netsuite

Using the latest NetSuite PHP Toolkit v2012_2, how can I get the contents of lists and in particular custom lists?

For example, we have a custom list with options for how the customer heard about us. We modify this list from time to time. When a visitor to our site gets to our registration screen we’d like to pull in from NetSuite the list items for the custom list with id 3 (along with each list item’s id) so we can fill a drop-down box for use when creating a contact in NetSuite. This way we can maintain a single list in NetSuite and it will always be current in the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps http://tellsaqib.github.com/NSPHP-Doc/ could help you in coding it yourself.

Comment: Well, thanks for the kick in the pants! *smile* Turns out the SearchMultiSelectFieldOperator I was using was incorrect. Rather than "is" I needed "anyOf".

Answer (score 3):

Credit and thanks to Saqib!

For reference, here is an example of the code that is now working:

```
$service = new NetSuiteService();
$service->setSearchPreferences(false, 20);

$recordRef = new RecordRef();
$recordRef->internalId = 1;

$searchField = new SearchMultiSelectField();
$searchField->operator = "anyOf";
$searchField->searchValue = $recordRef;

$search = new CustomListSearchBasic();
$search->internalId = $searchField;

$request = new SearchRequest();
$request->searchRecord = $search;

$searchResponse = $service->search($request);
var_dump($searchResponse);
die();
```